# Why does "Emergency Force Sphere" not appear on the Sorcerer/Wizard spell list?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, wizard, sorcerer

So, I found out about [this spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/emergency-force-sphere/). I wanted to get it on my sorcerer but I got distracted and couldn't read the whole description. When I remembered again a moment later I went to look for this spell on the [Sorcerer/Wizard spell list](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/spell-lists-sorcerer-and-wizard/) to read the description in detail. To my surprise the spell was not on the list under 4th level evocation spells. As far as I can tell this is not a 3rd party spell, so is there a reason for it not being on the list? Or is this just a minor mistake?

Comment: Are you asking if there appears to be an error on www.d20pfsrd.com?

Comment: Well, I want to make sure whether this is an error or if there is a reason for it not being on the list and if there is a reason then I wonder if there are other spells like this one that don't appear on the spell list.

Comment: So just as an FYI to anyone who finds themselves here looking for a place that has missing spells. The app Pathbuilder for phones, seems to have the most complete list I have found, and lists sources for reference. Has even new soft covers from this year. However again, Not official. Take with a grain of salt and cross-reference material to ensure legality in games that heavily enforce no 3pp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the spell, as published, says it is on the wizard/sorcerer list, then it is.

The http://www.d20pfsrd.com is an **unofficial source** of information. Just like the [Archives of Nethys](http://archivesofnethys.com/Spells.aspx?Class=Wizard) (the spell is [there](http://archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Emergency%20Force%20Sphere) though). They are mostly maintained by fans, and as such, they are more prone to error.

The **official source** of online information about pathfinder is [Paizo's PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/). However, material published under softcover books hardly make it to the PRD, this spell being no exception. Usually only material published on hardcovers are published on the PRD (there are exceptions, see the [technology guide](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/technologyGuide/equipmentIntroduction.html)).

Answer (score 2):

It's propably an oversight : the spell lists by class have a lot of spells by Paizo missing, most of them being recent additions. The list in alphabetical order has every spell on the website, but it appears that spell lists by class weren't updated when new spells were added.