# Are the cantrips missing from d20pfsrd's sorcerer/wizard spell list page legal starting cantrips?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I noticed earlier today when looking at [cantrips](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/spell-lists-sorcerer-and-wizard/#TOC-0-Level-Sorcerer-Wizard-Spells-Cantrips-) for a potential character, that the list was not all inclusive. For example, the spell [Vacuous Vessel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vacuous-vessel/) was not listed, but is infact a 0th level sorcerer wizard spell. So I moseyed on over to the [rare cantrips](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/rare-cantrips/) page to see if it was there. Nope. Are these missing cantrips official starting cantrips to take or are they similar to rare cantrips?

Comment: Cutting this down to either *How is data added to d20PFSRD?* or *What are all the official 0-level Sor/Wiz spells?* might make this question more easily answered. That is, I suspect an issue with a specific Web site should be taken up with that Web site's owners, but a user may know and be willing to share how data is gathered and put on that site, and the latter is just a limited list. However, shopping for Web site that's more comprehensive than another Web site is beyond the site's scope. (Also, I'm guessing *legal* means *official*, but the question really should define that term.)

Comment: That spell *is* on the d20pfsrd (he links it).  Which list are you asking about (there’s maybe 10 ways to view spells on that site) and do you think there’s a reason other than “someone has to update lists?”  The spell db might be a more complete view.

Comment: Related: [Why does “Emergency Force Sphere” not appear on the Sorcerer/Wizard spell list?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101039/why-does-emergency-force-sphere-not-appear-on-the-sorcerer-wizard-spell-list/101042#101042)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/) is not official, its maintained by fans, and as such, its prone to error. This is just another example of such errors. [Paizo's PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/) is **official**, though it takes longer to be updated and not every book makes it there, specially softcovers.

I will try to not [repeat myself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101039/why-does-emergency-force-sphere-not-appear-on-the-sorcerer-wizard-spell-list/101042#101042), but if a published spell says that it is on a class's spell list, then it is. This also means that they are all *"legal"* if your GM allows it, or if the book has been sanctioned for [Society Play](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/additional) as a valid resource.

This also means that with every new cantrip published, new wizard characters begin with more spells on their spellbooks. As long as they research them properly and remember to write them down, as some GM's don't take "*all cantrips*" as a valid spellbook entry.

Comment: So as a quick update. I loaded up the pathbuilder app on my phone. And looked there. It seems up to date and lists 35 wizard cantrips vs SRDs 29. Just for anyone still looking for a list for the future.